# Help in applying the pigeonhole principle to this graph question

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory, proof-writing

Question: Prove in a finite graph with $\geq 2$ vertices that two vertices have the same degree.

I am essentially 90% done with the proof. Given $n = |V|$ for a finite graph $G = (V,E)$, I showed a vertex in the graph must have degree $< n$, and denoted a set $S = \{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$ which contains the possible degrees for each vertex. Both of $0,n-1$ cannot be in $S$, as a vertex connected to all vertices implies no vertex has a degree of $0$; likewise, the converse is true. So, the actual set $D$ of possible values is $\{1,2,...,n-1\}$ or $\{0,1,2,...,n-2\}$. In either case, $|D| = n - 1 < |V|$, so there is no injection from $|V|$ to $|D|$. I am not sure how to use this to show at least two vertices in $D$ share a value in $D$. Does this immediately follow?

Comment: So you're not allowing multi-edges?

Comment: Aren't you done? This already is a good proof.

Answer (score 2):

This is already a good proof.
But let me restate it -

For any given graph with n vertices ( n $\geq$ 2) possible degrees are 0 to n-1.

And as you have already pointed out 0 and n-1 can't be the degree of vertices simultaneously in a graph.

So for every vertex there are only n-1 possible degrees but there are n vertices so by pigeon hole principle at least two vertices will have the same degree.

Hope that helps !